# pipe curl to grep

Tags: curl

How do you get `curl` to send the downloaded pagge into pipe instead of just printing it on the screen

This works:

```
# curl -Ss -o txt https://pgl.yoyo.org/adservers/serverlist.php?showintro=0;hostformat=hosts
# grep 127 txt
```

But this does not:

```
# curl -Ss -o txt https://pgl.yoyo.org/adservers/serverlist.php?showintro=0;hostformat=hosts | grep 127
```

Can this be made to work without using an intermediate file?

Comment: It helps to understand what each flag in a command does - read `man curl` if you do not

Comment: Note that the unquoted semicolon in the URL introduces a new command in the shell (a variable assignment in this particular case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell `curl` not to write to a file (`-o txt`), and quote the URL:

```
curl -Ss 'https://pgl.yoyo.org/adservers/serverlist.php?showintro=0;hostformat=hosts' | grep 127
```

Your attempt doesn’t work because of the semicolon in the URL: if it’s not quoted, it is interpreted by the shell as ending a command. The shell thus runs

```
curl -Ss -o txt https://pgl.yoyo.org/adservers/serverlist.php?showintro=0
```

followed by

```
hostformat=hosts | grep 127
```

The latter works without a visible error because `hostformat=hosts` is a valid command, with no output.

Quoting also protects the `?` from causing problems (it’s a globbing wildcard).

Comment: The `-o txt` in my second command was a typo. However, you have provided the solution which is that the URL must be in quotes. Explain that!

Comment: See the updated answer. Feel free to edit your question to show what you really ran ;-).